# How to calculate datetime in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a very special select statement I need assistance with.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetLeaderEvents]
@ILCode nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    
    SELECT EventID,EventName,EventDate,EventTime,EventSeatCount,EventILCode 
    FROM tblEvent 
    WHERE EventILCode = @ILCode AND (CAST(EventDate + EventTime AS TheEventDateTime) AS datetime) >= CAST(GETDATE() AS datetime)

END
```

The issue is that after the AND in the WHERE clause, the sql syntax is incorrect but I have written it in the format that would clearly indicate what I am trying to do. I have separated my EventDate and EventTime into two different columns in the EventTable. I am trying to filter out events that are older than the current date and time of the system. If I try and compare the EventTime and EventDate separately  like this:

```
WHERE EventILCode = @ILCode AND CAST(EventTime AS time) >= CAST(GETDATE() AS time) AND CAST(EventDate AS date) >= CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
```

Then if there is an event at 11:00AM on 20/08/2020 which is 16 days before writing this post and the second where clause is implemented then on any day before the 20th an event that is earlier than the current TIME will be hidden which is incorrect because the event will only take place on the 20th...

If there is a way too make this possible could someone please assist me or guide me in the correct direction. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, the `sp_` prefix is reserved by Microsoft for Special Procedures and should not be used for User Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below.

```
SELECT EventID,EventName,EventDate,EventTime,EventSeatCount,EventILCode 
FROM tblEvent 
WHERE EventILCode = @ILCode AND 
(CAST(EventDate AS datetime) + CAST(EventTime AS datetime)) >=  CAST(GETDATE() AS datetime)
```

or

```
SELECT EventID,EventName,EventDate,EventTime,EventSeatCount,EventILCode 
FROM tblEvent 
WHERE EventILCode = @ILCode AND 
(DATEDIFF(dd, 0,CAST(EventDate AS datetime) ) + CAST(EventTime AS datetime)) >=  CAST(GETDATE() AS datetime)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, I used the first coding block and that worked like a charm. You are a God send <3

Comment: @SeanClaasen, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too. You can also choose to up-vote the answer by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer.